# Understanding vector<shared_ptr<T> >, shared_ptr<vector<T> >, or vector<T>

Tags: c++, boost, stl

The Node is the data structure used to store the Node when we parse a graph.

Here is the sample code:

```
struct NodeA {
    vector<string> vecStrs; // the size of the vecStrs keeps increasing!
};
struct NodeB {
    vector<boost::shared_ptr<string> > vecShpStrs;
};

struct NodeC {
    boost::shared_ptr<vector<string> > shpVecStrs;
};

int main()
{
    NodeA nodeA;
    nodeA.vecStrs.push_back("stringA");    // input
    cout << "Output from NodeA: " << nodeA.vecStrs.front() << endl; // output

    NodeB nodeB;
    nodeB.vecShpStrs.push_back(boost::make_shared<string>("stringB"));
    cout << "Output from NodeB: " << *(nodeB.vecShpStrs.front()) << endl;

    NodeC nodeC;
    nodeC.shpVecStrs.reset(new vector<string>());
    nodeC.shpVecStrs->push_back("stringC");
    cout << "Output from NodeC: " << nodeC.shpVecStrs->front() << endl;
}
```

Please verify my understanding and see whether or not it is correct

**Question 1.1**> Whenever an instance of NodeB is copied, the collection of elements stored in the vector is also copied. Since each element is a shared_ptr, the copy operation is less expensive compared that of NodeA.

**Question 1.2**> Whenever an instance of NodeC is copied, the ONLY copied element is the shared_ptr and the underlying vector is NOT copied instead it is shared across all referred shared_ptr.

**Question 2**> The implement of NodeC should be used to make the copies least expensive. If that is the case(I doubt), why I see the usage of NodeB most of the time instead of NodeC?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.1) correct

1.2) correct

2.0) Because boost::shared_ptr primary use is not to provide cheap copies, but to manage lifetime. Otherwise a raw pointer would also suffice. A vector is often defined as member object and is automatically destroyed with its parent, where objects located in the vector are inserted, removed and moved around.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 2> The implement of NodeC should be used to make the copies
>   least expensive. If that is the case(I doubt), why I see the usage of
>   NodeB most of the time instead of NodeC?

As enigma said, is wrong to use NodeC for making copies, since you are not copying the vector, just sharing it (copying the smart pointer). For example:

```
NodeC nodeC;
nodeC.shpVecStrs.reset(new vector<string>());
nodeC.shpVecStrs->push_back("stringC");
assert(nodeC.shpVecStrs->size() == 1);

NodeC nodeC2 = nodeC;
nodeC2.shpVecStrs->push_back("other string");
assert(nodeC2.shpVecStrs->size() == 2);
assert(nodeC.shpVecStrs->size() == 2); // they are the same pointer.
```